# How to make NGinx to ignore file permissions?

Tags: nginx, file-permissions

I use NGinx to serve static sites, and sometimes there are some files with 640 permissions instead of 644. For such sites NGinx says "403 Forbidden".

Is there any way to **tell NGinx to ignore file permissions** and serve any file in the `public` directory?

P.S.

Yes, I can change the file permissions with `chmod`, but it happens frequently and I got tired of it.

Also, I'm aware about the possible security breach, but in this case I don't care about it, any file inside of `public` folder supposed to be available for everyone.

Comment: The three numbers you list are the permissions that the **Owner**, the **Group** and **Everyone else** have on those files.  Without telling us the owner and the group that the file has attached, only the last number has any meaning at all to us.  You should probably start by reading a tutorial on Unix file system permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is nonsense.

The user/group pair assigned to nginx worker process(es) is defined with the [user directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user). Change it so it has read access in relation to your OS users and groups.

Answer (score 3):

The file permissions are at the os level not at nginx.  so you need to make whatever puts the files into the directory update the permissions or you need to change nginx so it runs as a user/group that has permissions to read the file.

Answer (score 3):

Only processes owned by root can have access to everything regardless of permissions. nginx really should not be run as root.

What you **can** do is change the ACLs for a directory and its contents, so that one or more users or groups can have read access regardless of the file permissions. You should read `man setfacl` before playing around with it, but here's a short instruction:

First, take a backup of the current permissions:

```
sudo getfacl -R /path/to/public_dir > /tmp/publicacl.bak
```

Apply read access to all existing files in `/path/to/public_dir` and all subdirectories

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:NGINXUSR:rX /path/to/public_dir
```

Set a default ACL to `/path/to/public_dir` and all its subdirectories  which will be applied to all new files and directories created or uploaded in those directories

```
sudo setfacl -R -m d:u:NGINXUSR:rX /path/to/public_dir
```

If anything were to go wrong, you can revert to the earlier ACLs by doing

```
sudo setfacl --restore=/tmp/publicacl.bak
```

Answer (score -2):

simple solution would be to run a cron job to add read permission for nginx user to all the files in you public folder, any way you dont care about read permissions in public folder