# Root overwrite permission to user

Tags: centos, root

Our developers *WinSCP/Putty* and have a *dev* user on our web-server. The site directory they are working on is owned by apache, that restricts them to overwrite files through FTP/SFTP as *dev*. I have added the *dev* user to the apache group, yet it doesn't help. Even though they have *root* privileges they can't `sudo -s` through a FTP client. If I log them in with *root* through WinSCP I don't find an option to only restrict them to that specific directory. How can I solve this issue in a good way?

Comment: You might want to check wether the Apache group has write permissions to the directory in question.

Comment: Also check the config of the FTP server. It may do stuff with ownership that affects this.

Comment: Also, there's the option of using an ACL instead of/in addition to group permissions. See e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/629620/how-to-make-nginx-to-ignore-file-permissions/629762#629762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the apache group doesn't have write permission to the folder, check:

`ls -l /folder path`

if you see something close to rwxr-xr-x, then group only has read+exec on folder, use:

`chmod 775 -Rf /path to your folder`

in order to recursively add write permissions to folder group, hope this helps!

Set `apache` as the group owner of the site directory:

`chown :apache -R folder/`

Comment: My site directories are *drwxr-xr-x* and the site is owned by root. Should I change it to *apache*?

Comment: You can keep owner as root, but change group owner to apache using     chown :apache -R /folder. Now you can change group permission as I have mentioned in my answer above. Since your dev user is part of the apache group, user should acquire same permissions as group, which will allow write through FTP/FTPS when connected using dev user.

Comment: Note: once you change the group permission, run another ls -l on folder, you should see permissions changed to drwxrwxr-x.